# Keep current position after refreshing CarouselView items

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.carouselview

i am using a CarouselView to display certain pages.

The collection is defined like this.

```
public IList<View> Pages { get; } = new ObservableCollection<View>();
```

The binding looks as follows in the xaml code.

```
<CarouselView x:Name="PageCarousel" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Reference PagePanelView}, Path=Pages}" IndicatorView="PageCarouselIndicator" Loop="False" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" IsScrollAnimated="False">
```

The user can trigger a refresh with a button. The refresh logic just calls a Pages.Clear() and adds them again. For keeping the current position i use the ScrollTo(int index).

Unfortunately this does not work as expected, because the CarouselView shows always the first page after refreshing.

Xamarin.Forms version is 5.0.0.2083.

Thanks.

Comment: How about, instead of clearing the list, only remove and add entries to it? Otherwise you need to keep track of current position and somehow hook into the adapter/data source to scroll back to the correct position when reloading your data.

Comment: instead of describing the refresh logic, try posting the actual code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the ScrollTo with animate: true instead of false seems to fix the issue.